# Biggest component searching in a 3 dimensional torus graph

Tags: probability-or-statistics, graphs-and-networks

I made a Mathematica code, which search the biggest component of red points in a 3-dimensional, $n\times n\times n$ torus graph. The torus points are drawed red color with the probability of p, the other points aren't drawed (p is a parameter). And if two red points are "neighbours", there are edges in the graph.

I used in my code adjacencymatrices and AdjacencyGraph. But this code requires too much memories, and I can simulate this program just to n=35.

I'd like to simulate this simulation for n=100.

There is my code:

```
n = {5, 15, 25};

p = Range[0, 1, 0.01];

NoSample = 10;

grid = Map[ParallelTable[If[Mod[i - j, #^3] == 1 || Mod[j - i, #^3] == 1 || Mod[i - j, #^3] == # || Mod[j - i, #^3] == # || Mod[i - j, #^3] == #^2 || Mod[j - i, #^3] == #^2, 1, 0], {j, 1, #^3}, {i, 1, #^3}] &, n];

g = Map[AdjacencyGraph, grid];

reds=Table[Transpose[DeleteCases[Table[Map[Range[n[[i]]^2]*RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#], n[[i]]^2] &, p], NoSample], x_ /; x == 0, {3}]], {i, 1, Length[n]}];

values = Table[Map[Mean,Map[Max[Map[Length, ConnectedComponents[Subgraph[g[[i]], #]]]]/n[[i]]^2 &, reds[[i]], {2}], {1}], {i, 1, Length[n]}];

ListPlot[values]
```

[image]

My questions are from this code:

-Can anyone help me, how can I simulate this simulation for n=100, for example with an another method, which don't requires too much memories like the AdjacencyGraph?

-If anyone can simulate for n=100, can share there the plot?

Comment: Regarding the graph construction, you can use `SparseArray` with a pattern argument (`{i_,j_} /; condition -> 1`) to save memory. You can go further and use `Band`: then you only have to test every `i-j` difference, not every `{i,j}` pair. This will be much faster.  I did not program this, but this is what I would do. You should also consider using `f/@list` instead of `Map[f, list]`. I find the latter unreadable when several maps are nested.

Answer (score 2):

The execution time is 58 seconds.

**In:**

```
(*Generate SparseArray*)
(*Method 1, faster *)

sparseArrayFromPositionValueRules[n_] := 
 Module[{upperPositions, lowerPositions, allPositions, 
   positionValueRules},
  upperPositions[k_, p_] := Table[{i, i + k^p}, {i, 1, k^3 - k^p}];
  lowerPositions[k_, p_] := Table[{i + k^p, i}, {i, 1, k^3 - k^p}];
  allPositions[k_] := 
   ParallelTable[
     linePoints[k, 
      p], {linePoints, {upperPositions, lowerPositions}}, {p, 
      Range[0, 2]}] // Flatten[#, 2] &;
  positionValueRules[k_] := 
   allPositions[k] // Map[# -> 1 &] // Append[#, {k^3, k^3} -> 0] &;
  SparseArray@positionValueRules[n]]

(*Method 2, fast*)

sparseArrayFromBands[n_] := 
 Module[{bandPositions, positionsToBands, bands},
  bandPositions[k_] := 
   Table[Permutations@{1, 1 + k^p}, {p, Range[0, 2]}] // Catenate;
  positionsToBands[positions_, k_] := 
   positions // Map[# -> 1 &] // 
     Join[#, {{k^3, 1} -> 0, {1, k^3} -> 0}] & // 
    Map[Band@First@# -> Last@# &];
  bands[k_] := bandPositions[k] // positionsToBands[#, k] &;
  SparseArray@bands[n]]

(*Comparasion of Method 1 and Method 2*)
(*DiscretePlot[
{First@AbsoluteTiming@sparseArrayFromPositionValueRules[i],
First@AbsoluteTiming@sparseArrayFromBands[i]}, 
{i,5,100,5}, 
PlotLegends\[Rule]"Expressions"]*)

graphsFromSparseArray[array_] := Module[{graph},
  graph = AdjacencyGraph[array];
  Table[graph, 3]]

(*Main*)
torusPlot[n_] := 
 Module[{sparseArray, graphs, reds, values, p = Range[0, 1, 0.01], 
   NoSample = 10},
  ns = Table[n, 3];
  Print[ns];

  sparseArray = sparseArrayFromPositionValueRules;
  graphs = graphsFromSparseArray@sparseArray[n];

  reds = Table[
    Transpose[
     DeleteCases[
      Table[Map[
        Range[ns[[i]]^2]*
          RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#], ns[[i]]^2] &, p], 
       NoSample], x_ /; x == 0, {3}]], {i, 1, Length[ns]}];
  values = 
   Table[Map[Mean, 
     Map[Max[Map[Length, 
          ConnectedComponents[Subgraph[graphs[[i]], #]]]]/ns[[i]]^2 &,
       reds[[i]], {2}], {1}], {i, 1, Length[ns]}];
  ListPlot[values]]

n = 10;
AbsoluteTiming@torusPlot[n]
```

**Out:**

{10,10,10}]
[image]

{100,100,100}
[image: {100,100,100}]

Comment: Thank you for this code and plotting, It helped me a lot.